# inserting values in to database only once

Tags: php

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    { 
      $tadd=$_POST["tadd"]; //getting values 
      $pname=$_POST["pname"]; 
      $date=$_POST["date"];
      $result=mysql_query("insert into pannel(tadd,pname,date)values('$tadd','$pname','$date')");
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
           alert('Quotation Generated Successfully!')
      </script>"; 
      } ?> 
     <center>
     <h1>Title</h1>
     </center>

 <form name="form" method="post" action="" onSubmit="submit;">
 <center><table border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:350px">

 <tr> <td><b>To Address</td> <td><textarea name="tadd" rows="5"
 cols="30"></textarea></td></tr>
     <tr> <td><b>Project Name</td> <td><input type="text" name="pname" required></td></tr>


  <tr> <td><b>Date</td> <td><input type="text" name="date"
 id="datepicker" required></td></tr>


 <tr> <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit"
 value="submit"/></td> </tr></center>  </table>   </form>
```

I have one record in my database with

```
id  tadd   pname    date
1    hello  vvv      22/10/2014
```

if i insert values into database again it should data already inserted

please help me regarding this issue

Comment: It should **what** data already inserted?

Comment: You can make your column(s) as UNIQUE as already stated, or you can check on SELECT with `mysql_num_rows()`, or `mysqli_num_rows()` or `rowCount()` if using PDO. If data exists in a particular row, you basically abort if it does. Many other ways to do this; these are but a few.

Comment: You shouldnt be using `mysql` as it is depraceted use either `mysqli` or `PDO`  and do you mean that you would like this to overwrite the current data and not add a new line?

Comment: The HTML is malformed (the `table` and `center` tags are nested incorrectly). It is also very old-fashioned (tables are for data, not forms, and the `center` tag is something that belongs to the past). The `onSubmit` attribute will also not do anything. And the `b` tag is not closed. And the `mysql_query` function is deprecated. And you are not checking that the POST variables are set before using them. And... well, you should find a more up-to-date tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `mysql_num_rows()` which is one way to do this, which I believe the goal is to avoid duplicates.

Sidenote: You can also set your column(s) as UNIQUE to avoid duplicates.

**N.B.**: I used the `pname` column as an example. It's up to you to check which one will always be unique in regards to a username for instance.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pannel where pname = '".$pname."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){

    echo "Already exists.";
}
else{
   mysql_query("insert into pannel (tadd, pname,date) values ('$tadd','$pname','$date')");
}
```

Do sanitize your data:

```
$tadd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["tadd"]);
```

and do the same for the others.

Even better, use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

- *They're much safer*, because your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

---

***Footnotes:***

You should get rid of `onSubmit="submit;"` in your form. As outlined in comments, it's not going to do anything.

---

**Edit:**

```
<?php 

// assuming DB connection has been made.

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$tadd= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["tadd"]);
$pname= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pname"]);
$date= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["date"]);

$query = "SELECT * FROM pannel where pname = '".$pname."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){

        echo "Already exists.";
        exit;
    }
    else{
       mysql_query("insert into pannel (tadd, pname,date) values ('$tadd','$pname','$date')");

       echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Quotation Generated Successfully!')</script>";
        }



  } // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>

<body>
 <center><h1>Title</h1></center>

 <form method="post" action="">
 <div align="center">
    <center>

 <table border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:350px">

 <tr> <td><b>To Address</td> <td><textarea name="tadd" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea></td></tr>
     <tr> <td><b>Project Name</td> <td><input type="text" name="pname" required></td></tr>

 <tr> <td><b>Date</td> <td><input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" required></td></tr>


 <tr> <td colspan="2" align="center">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
 </td> </tr>
 </table>
    </center>
 </div>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @vish Describe "not working". Are you in fact connected to DB?

Comment: its inserting into database multiple times

Comment: @vish Inserting multiple times at once, or meaning you can still enter duplicate data?

Comment: id  tadd   pname    date
1    hello  vvv      22/10/2014   2 hi bbb 22/4/2014

Comment: @vish I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Please explain in detail.

Comment: submitted first time in database 

id  tadd   pname    date
1    hello  vvv      22/10/2014

if i submit second time it stored as

id  tadd   pname    date
2   fdsv  ggg    20/10/2014


i dont want to insert second time into database

Comment: @vish I honestly don't know what you wish to achieve. You only want ONE piece of data in your table and not allow for anymore after that? I'm confused. What is the goal you wish to achieve?

Comment: want ONE piece of data in my table..i am editing code which u gave thanks for ur help

Comment: fred submitting first time inserting into database after refreshing page and if we insert it should display already inserted

Comment: @vish It will only show it is already inserted if there is matching data in the `pname` column. If you try and enter `bbb` for example, something you said you entered already, well if it's still in your database, and you try to enter it again, it will show you the message that it "Already exists".

Comment: fred but if i enter any data second time into database it should display "already exists"

Comment: Then you need to add conditions to the `WHERE` clause then, if you want to check if any of the data entered exists in your table and not just a single row. If that gets too complicated, then you will need to modify your columns to be `UNIQUE`, which is the simplest method without having to first do a `SELECT`.

Comment: can u provide me query once please

Comment: @vish `$query = "SELECT * FROM pannel where tadd = '".$tadd."' AND pname = '".$pname."' AND date = '".$date."' ";`
 -or- 
`$query = "SELECT * FROM pannel where tadd = '".$tadd."' OR pname = '".$pname."' OR date = '".$date."' ";` this is the best I can do. Try one of them once at a time, and not together.

Comment: @vish Sorry, I don't have time to chat. I cannot help you any longer, sorry.